# rqt_plot issues in indigo

Tags: ros-indigo, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ros node which publishes a custom message as well as sensor_msgs/JointState messages. Both show up correctly in rostopic echo but not in rqt_plot.

When starting up rqt_plot I see an error: could not get message class for topic type "MyCustomMsg" on topic "my_topic". The message does not show up in rqt_plot's dropdown menu, and can't be added if I type it in explicitly. The message is a float64[] array and should be accessible as my_topic/my_message_data[0] but this doesn't work. The problem is similar to this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/72739/cant-plot-some-messages-types-on-rqt_plot/ except that restarting doesn't solve it.

The second problem is with the JointState message and similar to https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/261 so the question is if this is fixed in the next indigo release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190686/rqt_plot-issues-in-indigo/) by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(1) Are you sure you have your custom workspace sourced properly when you started rqt_plot?

You should be able to close rqt_plot, and, **in the same terminal**, run `rosmsg show MyCustomMsg` to confirm that your workspace was set up properly.

(2) The second issue you linked to should be resolved in the next releases of rqt_plot and ros_comm. In the meantime, you should use both packages from source as recommended in the ticket.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on 2014-08-21**:
It is entirely possible that the first issue was caused by not having the workspace sourced properly, because the problem is gone - but I can make it appear by skipping the sourcing step.

The second issue I can live with for now until the next update. Interestingly enough an array works fine if it's defined as fixed size, so my custom message with a 6 element array works, but not JointState.

Thanks!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-21**:
According to the latest update on the ticket you linked to, the patches to rqt_plot are released and should be available for installation.